# Connecting iOS app with MobFox

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobfox

I followed the documentation to add MobFox ads in my application. For some reason I am getting the error : Could not connect to the server.

```
func mobFoxAdDidFailToReceiveAdWithError(_ error:Error!) {
        print("MobFoxAdDidFailToReceiveAdWithError: ", error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

And it gives:
MobFoxAdDidFailToReceiveAdWithError:  Could not connect to the server.

```
 private var mobfoxAd: MobFoxAd!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 200), size: CGSize(width:320, height: 50))
            mobfoxAd = MobFoxAd("fe96717d9875b9da4339ea5367eff1ec", withFrame: rect)
            mobfoxAd.delegate = self
            mobfoxAd.refresh = adRefresh as NSNumber?
            self.view.addSubview(mobfoxAd)
        }
```

In my Info.plist file, I have added.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
</dict>
```

I don't seem to find the reason.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the countries where these services are not provided are not mentioned.
If you face this problem, change to another country with VPN. Ads will appear.